# Dispatch Queue inside of Dispatch.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I am currently working on a project that requires me to update a database, and then loop over the database to compare some values. Because of the database update time I have decided to use a delayed call, to give it time to update. Here is the structure of my calls:

```
//Give database time to update
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() +5) {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    closure {
        ...data processing....
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    //wait for data-processing inside closure to complete
    dispatchGroup.wait()


}
```

This freezes my app. It was my understanding that the closure should run asynchronously and so I was hoping the enter/leave balance would be reached while at dispatchGroup.wait(). Any help for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Note also I occasionally get an EXC_BREAKPOINT error at the line I have indicated, in the following function:

```
- (void) fireEvent:(id <FEvent>)event queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue {
    if ([event isCancelEvent]) {
    FCancelEvent *cancelEvent = event;
    FFLog(@"I-RDB065001", @"Raising cancel value event on %@", event.path);
    NSAssert(self.cancelCallback != nil, @"Raising a cancel event on a listener with no cancel callback");
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        self.cancelCallback(cancelEvent.error);
    });
} else if (self.callback != nil) {
    FDataEvent *dataEvent = event;
    FFLog(@"I-RDB065002", @"Raising value event on %@", dataEvent.snapshot.key);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        self.callback(dataEvent.snapshot);  <---------
    });
}
```

Comment: "It was my understanding that the closure should run asynchronously" But it's the main thread.

Comment: you should not run a long running task on the main queue, you are dispatching as async but on the main queue, hence blocking UI.

Comment: Building in arbitrary time delays to allow for the execution of asynchronous tasks is fragile. There should be some sort of completion handler from your database update that you can either use to perform the calculation or post a notification so that some other object can be notified that the database update is complete.

Comment: adding to @Paulw11 please be aware that notifications can be posted to observers of the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch is asynchronous but you are running it on the main thread.

You can simply run it on the background thread, it won't bloack the UI.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

}
```

Comment: This makes sense, I ended up using this solution but with the AsyncAfter instead.. thanks!